# Inspect status of Node.js I/O threads

Tags: node.js

I would like to know if there is a way to inspect the status of NodeJS I/O threads. In particular:

- **how many** threads are in use?
- **when** did I/O operations of each thread begin?
- **who** is using the thread (e.g. in my case I want to check if the I/O operation is related to the Oracle DB driver)